# hitting a multipart url in nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, multipartform-data, form-data

I have a client code using form-data module to hit a url that returns a content-type of image/jpeg. Below is my code

```
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');

var form = new FormData();
//form.append('POLICE', "hello");
//form.append('PAYSLIP', fs.createReadStream("./Desert.jpg"));

console.log(form);
//https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-  1/c8.0.50.50/p50x50/10934065_1389946604648669_2362155902065290483_n.jpg?oh=13640f19512fc3686063a4703494c6c1&oe=55ADC7C8&__gda__=1436921313_bf58cbf91270adcd7b29241838f7d01a
form.submit({
    protocol: 'https:',
    host: 'fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net',
    path: '/hprofile-ak-xfp1/v/t1.0-1/c8.0.50.50/p50x50/10934065_1389946604648669_2362155902065290483_n.jpg?oh=13640f19512fc3686063a3494c6c1&oe=55ADCC8&__gda__=1436921313_bf58cbf91270adcd7b2924183',
    method: 'get'
}, function (err, res) {
    var data = "";
    res.on("data", function (chunks) {
        data += chunks;
    });
    res.on("end", function () {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Response Headers - " + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    });
});
```

I'm getting some chunk data and the response headers i received was

```
{"last-modified":"Thu, 12 Feb 2015 09:49:26 GMT","content-type":"image/jpeg","timing-allow-origin":"*","access-control-allow-origin":"*","content-length":"1443","cache-control":"no-transform, max-age=1209600","expires":"Thu, 30 Apr 2015 07:05:31 GMT","date":"Thu, 16 Apr 2015 07:05:31 GMT","connection":"keep-alive"}
```

I am now stuck as how to process the response that i received to a proper image.I tried base64 decoding but it seemed to be a wrong approach any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Im trying to receive the chunk and upload into my server

Answer (score 1):

I expect that `data`, once the file has been completely downloaded, contains a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer).

If that is the case, you should write the buffer as is, without any decoding, to a file:

```
fs.writeFile('path/to/file.jpg', data, function onFinished (err) {
  // Handle possible error
})
```

See [fs.writeFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) documentation - you will see that it accepts either a string or a buffer as data input.

#### Extra awesomeness by using streams

Since the `res` object is a readable stream, you can simply pipe the data directly to a file, without keeping it in memory. This has the added benefit that if you download really large file, Node.js will not have to keep the whole file in memory (as it does now), but will write it to the filesystem continuously as it arrives.

```
form.submit({
    // ...
}, function (err, res) {
    // res is a readable stream, so let's pipe it to the filesystem
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('path/to/file.jpg')
    res.on('end', function writeDone (err) {
        // File is saved, unless err happened
    })
    .pipe(file) // Send the incoming file to the filesystem
})
```

Comment: I tried your approach but the file does not seem to be containing the correct format.

Comment: What does it contain? Most importantly, what does `data` contain?

Comment: data contains the raw image data..i dont want to send a file .. i want to make sure that i get the proper response from the url and send it back to a another user via my nodejs server. ie i want to send back the proper raw data and not as a file

Comment: In that case, just send him the raw image data, the buffer. Just as you would send him a string. Only make sure you set the proper `content-type` to `image/jpeg` or similar, if it's a different image type, **before** you start sending the data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The chunk you got is the raw image. Do whatever it is you want with the image, save it to disk, let the user download it, whatever.

Comment: how do i view the image from raw image is there any additional code to be done or tool to do the same

Comment: "View" it how? NodeJS can't "view" anything, it doesn't have a GUI.

Comment: i mean not in nodejs any other tool

Comment: Just open it like you would any other file (Assuming you did save it to disk)

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question clearly, you want to download a file from an HTTP endpoint and save it to your computer, right? If so, you should look into using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module instead of using form-data.

Here's a contrived example for downloading things using request:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request')

request('http://www.example.com/picture.jpg')
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('picture.jpg'))
```

Where `'picture.jpg'` is the location to save to disk. You can open it up using a normal file browser.